# jquery, jsonp and no success

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have the following jquery in my code`$j.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/WWTestHarnessWEB/ReadersToolkitFinalController.htm?jsoncallback=?", {'uID': 1}, function(data){alert(data);});`

The json that i am returning looks like the following `({"positiveCount":"0","negativeCount":"999"})`

But my alert is never firing.

Any idea what i need to do to ensure that this will work?

regards
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you're using a different name for the callback query string parameter than `callback` (looks like you're using `jsoncallback` instead), you have to tell jQuery; see the `jsonp` parameter in the options object on the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. This means you'll have to use `ajax` instead of `getJSON`, but that's easy enough.

E.g.:

```
$.ajax({
  url:      "http://localhost:8080/WWTestHarnessWEB/ReadersToolkitFinalController.htm?jsoncallback=?",
  dataType: "json",
  jsonp:    "jsoncallback",
  data:     {'uID': 1},
  success:  function(data){alert(data);}
});
```

I'm not sure whether you need to (or should) include the "jsoncallback=?" in the URL yourself or let jQuery put it in; a quick experiment should tell you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$j.getJSON(
  "http://localhost:8080/WWTestHarnessWEB/ReadersToolkitFinalController.htmjsoncallback=?", 
  {'uID': 1}, 
  function(data, status){
    alert(status);
  });
```

what does this output?

Comment: What happened to that URL? Surely initial `?` starts the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Does your server code actually obey the `jsoncallback` parameter?  If I understand you correctly, you're just returning

```
({"positiveCount":"0","negativeCount":"999"})
```

whereas the P in JSONP means you need to return

```
callback1234({"positiveCount":"0","negativeCount":"999"})
```

where `callback1234` is the value of the `jsoncallback` parameter.  (Although the URL says `jsoncallback=?`, JQuery interprets that specially, and replaces the `?` with a unique generated string.)

Also, [what T. J. Crowder said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914520/jquery-jsonp-and-no-success/2914644#2914644).

Answer (score 0):

Cheers guys for the responses.

It turned out that it was very finicky and by applying bits and pieces of what you guys showed me worked

here now is my jquery code `$j.getJSON( 
              "http://localhost:8080/WWTestHarnessWEB/ReadersToolkitFinalController.htm?jsoncallback=?",

              {'uID': 1},

              function(data, status){ 
                  if (status != 'success')
                  {
                      alert("Status is: " + status);
                  }
                  var positiveCount = data.positiveCount;

                  var negativeCount = data.negativeCount;
                  $j('td[id*="posiiveVoteId"]').html(getCorrectCountString(positiveCount));
                  $j('td[id*="negativeVoteId"]').html(getCorrectCountString(negativeCount));
              });`

My json response is as follows `ParamsHeadersPostPutResponseCacheHTMLJSON
Response Headersview source
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  80
Date    Wed, 26 May 2010 16:38:43 GMT
Request Headersview source
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept  text/javascript, application/javascript, */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://localhost:8080/WWTestHarnessWEB/jsp/ReadersToolkit/Json.jsp
Cookie  JSESSIONID=93FDA3BD0D2450D7FA4BD9A76C388F8A

jsonp1274891923240({"positiveCount":"0","negativeCount":"999"})`

Thanks again
Damien